# ember, how get "name" atribute among many links?

Tags: attributes, ember.js

Im starter in Ember. I've many links (i.e.), with attritube "name", and I want to get this attribute when I make click in one of them. I know how to work with only one and bindAttr, but with more I'm trying with this code, but is not working. I need to use many bindAttr???, for every link?, yesterday I made this (for only one link):

```
<body>

    <div id="templateHere"></div>

            <!--handlebar-->
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="text">
            <h1>Send the message:</h1>              
            <a {{action "clicked" on="click"}} name='link1'>Click me!!</a>
            <a {{action "clicked" on="click"}} name='link2'>click me again</a>
    </script>​





    <script>
            //namespace
            App = Ember.Application.create();

            //define view 
            App.myview = Ember.View.extend({
                            templateName: 'text',
                            name_attribute:'name_buttooooon',               
                            message: '',
                            clicked: function(event) {
                            console.log(jQuery(this).attr('name'));//get attribute name value
                            }                               
            });

            //create view
            App.myview=App.myview.create();

            //insert view in body
            $(function() {
                App.myview.append('#templateHere');
            });

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Why would you use the same action for both buttons, and not two different actions ? {{action cancel}} and {{action save}} ? I find it strange that you would need to fire the same action "clicked" for both buttons, as they would most likely have a different meaning to the user.

Comment: OK, really I aggree with you, is not a real case, Im playing only, so maybe is better if I change the buttons for Links. But in that case (with links), and only one action, is possible to get for example the attribute id?, or another one?

Comment: You could also vary the context on each action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this by using `event.currentTarget`. Its a [jQuery property](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/):

> Description: The current DOM element within the event bubbling phase.
>
> This property will typically be equal to the this of the function.
>
> If you are using jQuery.proxy or another form of scope manipulation, this will be equal to whatever context you have provided, not event.currentTarget

I guess Ember make some special context for events, because the jQuery doc said the `currentTarget` should be equal to `this`.

So it looks like this in your code:

```
clicked: function(event) {
    console.log($(event.currentTarget).attr('name'));
}
```

You can try this solution [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvMbC/).